# Animating background color to transition through colors on html element causes 100% cpu load

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create an effect where small dots on the html background gradually change color in an infinite loop. I have a 960px centred design so the background area can get quite large.

My solution was to set the background-color to a default color then tile a square grey image with a transparent corner knocked out over the top - so it shows the background through it.

I've then used the jQuery UI libabry to animate the changing background color:

```
  $("#root")   
      .animate({fontSize:"1em"},pause)          
      .animate( { backgroundColor: 'blue' }, transition)
      .animate({fontSize:"1em"},pause)      
      .animate( { backgroundColor: 'darkred' },transition);
```

This works but theres a big problem!

During the period where the `backgroundColor` is transitioning my CPU (firefox) usage goes to 100%.

so,

Is this the solution you would use?

If it is any ideas how to sort out the CPU usage?

Also how do you loop the animations?

Comment: This doesn't surprise me, the whole page is being redrawn in the background if you do this...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using jquery, maybe you should consider replacing your dot background with animated GIFs or PNGs?

Comment: Blimey, not sure why I didn't think of that! Thanks Spike. I have a habbit of over complicating things :-)
Hopefully I can get the gif at a reasonale file size and it should be a winner. -John

Comment: The gif only needs to be 1x1 pixel so the file size should be ok. If the animation would be smooth enough though, is a whole other question.

Answer (score 0):

The 100% CPU utilization seems to be a common thread among long-running jquery animations, from what I've read on SO.

If your animations happen slowly, instead of doing a single .animate() call to go from 'blue' to 'darkred', try using a timer to make the animation happen in tiny increments (every 100ms or so).

Or use an animated GIF as suggested above. It would save you lots of hassle.